# VB.net Select datagrid row depend on textbox.text equal to specific column

Tags: vb.net, select, datagrid, row

I need to add specific row from datagrid to another depends to intering a value in textbox witch is supposed to be equals to a cell in the first column in datagrid ...
In form Public Class

```
dim nom as integer=0
```

In Button

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Try
        nom = nom + 1
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(nom, Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value(), Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value(), QTY.Text, Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(5).Value())
        Barcode.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

In textbox_TextChanged I stock...
I know I most change the 00 on  Me.DataGridView1.Rows(?) to insert the right row !!!
HOW...

Answer (score 0):

I just do this way ,simply filtering the grid before add the rows....

```
  Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource.Filter = String.Format("BACODE= '" & Barcode.Text & "'")
        nom = nom + 1
        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(nom, Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value(), Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value(), QTY.Text, Me.DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(5).Value())
        Barcode.Text = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

This will let the first row become the desired row ...not perfect way except it work!